# Anaconda installed CUDA CUdnn and Tensorflow, Why doesn't find the GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

I'm using Anaconda prompt to install:
Tensorflow 2.10.0
cudatoolkit 11.3.1
cudnn 8.2.1

[image: 1]

I'm using Windows 11 and a RTX 3070 Nvidia graphic card. And all the drives have been updated.

And I tried downloading another version of CUDA and CUdnn in exe.file directly from CUDA website. And
added the directories into system path.The folder looks like this:

[image: 2]

But whenever I type in:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

It gives me Num GPUs Available:  0

And surely it eats my CPU for computing everything.

[image: 3]

It once succeeded when I used Colab and use GPU as the accelerator then created a session using my GPU. That time the GPU load has been maximized. But later don't know how, I can't use my own GPU for training in Colab or even their default free GPU.

Please help. ChatGPT doesn't give me correct information since it only referred to knowledge before 2020. It keeps asking me to install 'tensorflow-gpu' which has already been removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1` for  for GPU support with `TensorFlow 2.10` as per this [build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

Please check the **steps by step instructions** mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install tensorflow with GPU setup in the Anaconda environment.

Also, make sure all the **Hardware and Software requirements** are fulfilled given in the link and set the [path](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#set_your_path) to bin directory after downloading these software.

Answer (score 0):

cuda 11.2 and cudnn 8.6 seems to work with tensorflow 2.10 with python 3.10.9